# fancyBox 2.1.4: different size in IE and Chrome?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-plugins, fancybox

I am using fancyBox 2.1.4 and jQuery 1.9.1. When I show this fancybox on IE 10.0.9200, It display this box in compressed. But In chrome it is showing in perfect size.

I am using this MVC4 project.

### IE 10.0 (shrinked)

[image]

### Chrome (Perfect)

[image]

### Fancybox

```
@section Scripts {    
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Bootstrap")     
@Styles.Render("~/Content/DataTables/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/DataTables") 
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/fancybox")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/jquery.fancybox.css")
<script type="text/javascript">
  function display_dialog(id, name, custNo) {
        $.fancybox.open({
            href: 'Member/Details/' + custNo,
            type: 'ajax',
            padding: 5,
            openEffect: 'fade',
            openSpeed: 'normal',
            closeEffect: 'elastic',
            closeSpeed: 'slow',
            title: 'Details for: ' + name,
            mimWidth: 'auto',
            mimHeight: 'auto',
            helpers: {
                title: {
                    type: 'float'
                }
            }
        });
    }

</script>
}
```

### Update

after adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >` this works perfect.

Comment: I bet it's because you don't have a proper `DOCTYPE` and IE is switching to quirks mode

Comment: maybe just a typo, but have you tried minWidth rather than mimWidth?

Comment: @JFK `<!DOCTYPE html>` declared under `_layout.cshtml` page. May be you are right, CSS of some pages are weird and Chrome looks good. How to fix this?

Comment: @JFK , you are correct. I just added `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >` works perfect. thanks

Answer (score 0):

after adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >` this works perfect.